# I compiled ffmpeg and somehow installed it to /usr/local/bin/bin/ffmpeg. Can I move it myself without causing errors?

Tags: ffmpeg, paths

Since terminal can't find it anyways, I would assume it's safe to move, but I'm not sure how that would affect other files that either rely on ffmpeg install path if they do. FWIW I used

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

to configure the package, then `sudo make install` in a separate terminal on accident, although I don't think that should make a difference. I had also removed an older ffmpeg after `sudo make install` but that was a repo package installed in /usr.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The problem you SHOULD be asking about is "*terminal can't find it*" which is [very easy to fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path).

Comment: Since you ran `sudo make install` in a different terminal, and therefore possibly in a different directory, did it actually execute properly? Or did you get `make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.` meaning nothing happened? Is `ffmpeg` actually in `/usr/local/bin`? If no, then your `sudo make install` probably didn't do anything as mentioned before. Also, why and where do you want to move it?

Comment: If I recall correctly `/usr/local/bin` is in the vanilla Ubuntu `PATH`, so you don't need to add this directory to the `PATH`. Only reason I can think of that terminal does not find it is if it did not actually install to `/usr/local/bin`, or if you are using the same terminal session that previously executed the repo `ffmpeg`, then installed the compiled `ffmpeg`, but the hash index was not updated. See output of `hash`. Should not show `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` but should show `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`. If not, then run `hash -d ffmpeg` and try running again.

Comment: @user535733 - thanks for that link, that should solve it; I'm going to check where ffmpeg's default path should be and put it there.

Comment: @llogan - it executed without error, and it along with its requisite files are located in /usr/local/bin. I've been looking and I believe that shouldn't have actually caused an error using different terminals, since running `sudo make install` would use the configuration in which `--prefix=/usr/local/bin` was defined. The thing I'm having trouble finding information on is moving `ffmpeg` from `/usr/local/bin/bin` to `/usr/local/bin` because I am assuming `ffmpeg` being nested in a folder is causing an issue. By the way, `hash` output:  `1    /bin/ps` and the command didn't find `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @avisitoritseems I didn't notice the extra `/bin`! It won't execute like that. Just move the binary from `/usr/local/bin/bin` to `/usr/local/bin`. Not sure why it installed like that: it should have respected your `--prefix`: I have never seen this odd behavior. Also, it should have installed to `/usr/local/bin` if you omitted `--prefix`. The different terminal would have failed if it spawned to `~/` and the current directory was not your ffmpeg source directory, but that appears not to be the case.

Comment: Hm...odd. And yes, you're right. I suppose I was using old instructions. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate the help from the comments, turns out I did not need to edit my `PATH` nor do anything intensive.

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/bin/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin
```

worked, and I did move the other file in there that I can't recall the name of.